# pushing objects into existing array with php

Tags: php, arrays

In JS I would do something like this:

```
var arr = [];  
arr.push({ 
   sku : foo, 
   quantity: bar 
});
```

How do I do this with PHP?
When I try to do this I'm getting a parsing error.

For example with PHP:

```
$someArray = array(); // or maybe someArray = []; ???
$someArray = array_push(
  'sku' => $sku,
  'quantity' => $quantity
);
```

Is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: thx for link, I checked this, but the prob is not with adding 1 value to the existing array. I'm having a trouble with the key/value pairs.

Comment: `$someArray = array_push([
  'sku' => $sku,
  'quantity' => $quantity
]);` perhaps?

Comment: it looks like you are trying to pass an array into an array so you can array_merge() maybe.

Comment: $arrayName[] = $addItem; is faster than array_push

Comment: @MarkBaker that is what i needed . thx

Answer (score 3):

check this: [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

you could do:

```
$array = [];
array_push($array, "item");
```

or

```
$array = [];
$item = "hi";
$array['key'] = $item;
```

or you could use

```
$array = [];
array_merge($array, ["abc" => 1]);
```

also your js code is equivilant to

```
$array = [];
array_push($array, ['item' => 'value', 'item1' => 'value1']);


// is equivalent to 
var arr = [];  
arr.push({ 
   sku : foo, 
   quantity: bar 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for an array_push function. See ex:

```
$arr = [];
$arr['sku'] = $sku;
$arr['quantity'] = $quantity;
```

when handling key -> value pairs.

Edit (multidimensional one):

```
for($a=0; $a < $total ; $a++)
{    
  $arr[$a]['sku'] = $sku;
  $arr[$a]['quantity']  = $quantity;
}
```

Comment: I am looping over data and need to push them into the master array. The method you have described here will overwrite. I need to keep pushing each new sku/quantity into the master array.

Comment: Then I can think of two easy options. You can either insert the array to the master array after each iteration, or you can keep the data in a multi-dimensional array. Check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

This was accomplished by the following:

```
array_push($someArray, ["sku" => $sku, "quantity" => $quantity]);
```